# JavaScript RegEx to split a string of time to an array of separate strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, node-modules

So, I have this string `5h2m40s67ms`.
How do I split it so that I get `5h`, `2m`, `40s` and `67ms`?

This is so I can later convert them to timestamps later with the node_module `ms` and add them to the total time in milliseconds.

I've already tried `/[0-9][a-zA-Z]/g`, but it gives `0s` instead of `40s` and `7m` instead of `67ms`.
Is there an alternative to this process that can convert joined time strings (like `5h2m40s67ms`) to timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split()` consumes the separator as far as I know. `match()` can be a better pick here:

```js
const input="5h2m40s67ms";
const parts=input.match(/\d+[hms]+/g);
for(let part of parts)
  console.log(part);
```

oh, and you need the `+` to match 1 or more characters of a kind.

Comment: Thanks but could you edit the answer so that any alphabet is supported (like `hr`, `mo`, `yr`) and not just `hms`.

Comment: @WiseDevHelper your own one from the question can do that already, just with `match()` and `+`: `input.match(/[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+/g)`